# Which type of server runs in App engine?

Tags: android, node.js, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App engine server with flexible environment in nodejs, now i have added my domain name which i got from GoDaddy on app engine, now i want to add SSL certs on my app engine and also for my android app (which is using Retrofit) and for that first i need to download my certs from godaddy but when i am trying to download the certificate it is asking me for which server type i want to add SSL, now can anyone please tell me where can i find what type of server is running in my nodejs App engine i have checked everywhere on google cloud console, but haven't found any detail about that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The server type matters only for the specific instructions for obtaining your CSR info, but the CSR info itself is not dependent on the server type. From the [Generate a CSR (certificate signing request)](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/generate-a-csr-certificate-signing-request-5343):

> Our certificates are compatible with all types of web servers, even if
>   we do not have CSR instructions for them.

You can see the content of the CSR info in some of these instructions, for example [NGINX: Generate CSRs (Certificate Signing Requests)](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/nginx-generate-csrs-certificate-signing-requests-3601):

[image]

In other words you can use any instructions for obtaining the CSR that can be applied to your environment, including those from other SSL certificate issuers.

In fact the `openssl` tool used in the above recipe identically applies to other recipes. See, for example Comodo's [CSR Generation: Using OpenSSL (Apache w/mod_ssl, NGINX, OS X)](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1/19/csr-generation-using-openssl-apache-wmod_ssl-nginx-os-x):

> To generate a pair of private key and public Certificate Signing
>   Request (CSR) for a webserver, "server", use the following command :
>
> ```
> openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
> ```

I personally used the same `openssl` invocation on Linux to get the CSR for the certificate for my standard env python GAE app.

Comment: can you please look at my this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236228/ssl-from-godaddy-not-matching-from-the-ssl-getting-by-running-openssl-from-comma

Comment: What is domain name.key ?? Also when i have downloaded my certs i got two .crt files.